# Apache Ignite Server and Istio 1.11 connectivity issues

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, istio

Has anyone been able to get Apache ignite to work with Istio on Kubernetes.
I have Apache Ignite client and server pod communication working successfully on Kubernetes but once envoy sidecar is injected we get the following error:

```text
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiOperationTimeoutException: Failed to perform handshake due to timeout (consider increasing 'connectionTimeout' configuration property).
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.handshakeTimeoutException(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3894) [ignite-core-2.8.1.jar!/:2.8.1]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.safeTcpHandshake(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:4138) [ignite-core-2.8.1.jar!/:2.8.1]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3607) [ignite-core-2.8.1.jar!/:2.8.1]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Any help here , would be much appreciated?

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? Istio version and all related configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to add annotation to the deployment

```
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: "47100,47500"
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts: "47100,47500"
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about the annotations and how they solve the issue?